# Why is jQuery not working in my rails 5 app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am trying to write my first js code in my new Rails5 app and cannot seem to get Jquery to work, guessing it's a config/environment issue but despite all my searching and confirg alterations I cannot seem to get it running. Can anyone see what it is that I'm doing wrong?:

gemfile;

```
 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
```

application.html.erb;

```
<title>MyEngine</title>
<!-- Gon::Base.render_data -->
<%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

new.html.erb;

```
<%= link_to 'Remove Employee', '#', id: 'hide-employee' %>
```

quotes.coffee;

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
    $('#hide-employee').click ->
        alert "Clicked!"
```

And no alert when clicked. No errors, server running and page rendering fine, just nothing in console.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: in case somebody experiences this issue and you have already done the changes recommended for adding turbolinks:load, and still the issue is persisting,check if you have a similar .coffee file. Use the .coffee file or remove it and use the .js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using turbolinks:load instead.

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#hide-employee').click ->
    alert 'Clicked!'
```

Comment: Thanks @hashrocket, worked straigt away upon change.

Answer (score 2):

For those coming here because they have Rails 5.1, **jQuery is no longer a default dependency**. From the [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#jquery-no-longer-a-default-dependency):

> jQuery was required by default in earlier versions of Rails to provide features like data-remote, data-confirm and other parts of Rails' Unobtrusive JavaScript offerings. It is no longer required, as the UJS has been rewritten to use plain, vanilla JavaScript. This code now ships inside of Action View as rails-ujs.
>
> You can still use jQuery if needed, but it is no longer required by default.

To add it back in, add to the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'             # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
```

and then

```
$ bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

The **page:change** event is defined in [turbolinks-classic](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic). This version is now deprecated like you can see by yourself.

Instead, you can use [turbolinks:load or turbolinks:render or turbolinks:before-render](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events).

Comment: Thanks for the info  appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
```

Note: If you're using Rails 5.1 you can omit `//= require jquery_ujs` in favor of `//= require rails-ujs`.

Also, consider removing turbolinks entierly. Doing so has resolved more asset pipeline issue than I care to count. I have a feeling it's not providing you much value anyway. :-)

**Remove turbolinks with:**

1. Remove turbolinks from the *Gemfile* and `$ bundle`.
2. Remove `//= require turbolinks` from *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*
3. Remove both of the `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` hashes from *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*.

Comment: Thanks Kit. Now I've followed your suggestion and removed turbolinks from the app just as directed, however jQuery won't work again? Any ideas?`$(#hide-employee).click(function(){
    alert("link was clicked.");
}); ` does not do anything.